# Eigenvalue of a linear operator

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ with dimension $n$. Then, is it necessary that $T$ has $n$ eigen values or could it be less than $n$?

Comment: The other answers are more worth reading, but just to quickly answer your question: there could be anywhere between $0$ and $n$ eigenvalues.

Comment: It's always $n$... if you define "eigenvalue" and count them the right way.

Answer (score 10):

Depends on your field. For an algebraically closed field, all eigenvalues can be found and the linear transformation will have $n$ eigenvalues (of course, including multiplicity). But you may not be able to "find" all eigenvalues, if your field is, say $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 9):

It could be less than $n.$

Consider $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

1 is an eigenvalue, and $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector, but there is not a second independent eigenvector.

Comment: However, there is a 2nd independent *generalized* eigenvector.

Comment: @PaulSinclair The question was about eigenvalues, not eigenvectors.

Comment: Does the matrix I provided have a second eigenvalue?  Nonetheless, it is easy to show that the characteristic polynomial could have multiple roots for any single eigenvalue.  It is relevant, that there is not necessarily a space of eigenvectors associated with that value of dimension equal to the multiplicity.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen - Yes, but I was not answering the question. I am not contradicting Doug M's post, just adding some relevant information. While the eigenspaces of an operator do not necessarily span the entire complex vector space, the generalized eigenspaces always will. So the number of eigenvalues counted by dimension of the eigenspaces may be less than $n$, but when counted by dimension of the generalized eigenspaces (which match the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue as a root of the characteristic polynomial), it will always be $n$.

Comment: @Doug M. It doesn't have another independent eigenvector. However, while an eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda$ satisfies $$(A - \lambda I)v = 0$$ a *generalized eigenvector* satisfies the equation $$(A - \lambda I)^kv = 0$$ for some integer $k > 0$. If $A$ is your matrix, then $(A-1\cdot I)^2 = 0$, so every vector is a generalized eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue 1.

Answer (score 5):

If $T:\, V \rightarrow V$ then it admits the matrix representation with respect to some base of $V$. The eigenvalues are then computable (and defined) as the roots of the monic polynomial $p(\lambda )$
$$p(\lambda)=\text{det}(A-\lambda I),$$
where $A$ is the matrix representation of $T$ in the given base. As the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) states, any polynomial in $\mathbb{C}$ (and hence also in $\mathbb{R}$) of degree $n$ has exactly $n$ complex roots. Hence the answer is that there are always exactly $n$ eigenvalues, however not necesserily real.

Note that the finite-dimension of $V$ is necessery, for infinite-dimensional case the operators can have only finitely many eigenvalues.

Comment: Actually I think you need the root-factor-theorem also. But other than that really good answer

Comment: Thanks for reminding. That is true of course, however for the clasic fields $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ this is somewhat automatically assumed (at least as I have seen). Nonetheless, you are right.

Comment: Note that this is counting the eigenvalues by (algebraic) multiplicity.  There need not be $n$ **distinct** roots.

Answer (score 0):

A rotation transformation on the real Euclidean plane has no eigenvalues, except if it’s a rotation through a multiple of $\pi$ radians, in which case, the eigenvalues are 1 with multiplicity 2 (for rotations through a multiple of $2\pi$ radians) or -1 with multiplicity 2 (in case it’s a rotation through an odd multiple of $\pi$ radians).  For example, for a rotation through $\pi/4$ radians, no nonzero vector is mapped to a multiple of itself, so that rotation has no eigenvectors.  Having no eigenvectors, it has no eigenvalues.  However, relative to the standard ordered basis, it’s represented by a real matrix A that defines a linear operator U on the two-dimensional complex vector space consisting of (2x1) complex column vectors, and that real matrix A has two non-real (in fact purely imaginary) eigenvalues, because the linear operator U has two linearly independent non-real eigenvectors, and the corresponding eigenvectors are i and -i.

Thus a matrix with two distinct eigenvalues can represent a linear operator that has no eigenvalues, and that same matrix can represent a linear operator that has two distinct eigenvalues (in an extension field).